# Chromium not opening URLs

Tags: chromium, xdg-open

I have installed the nightly build of Chromium using [this](https://github.com/tgkokk/chromium-downloader-updater) script I created.

I have set it as default web browser, although opening URLs via `gnome-open` and `xdg-open` just opens a new tab.

Using the executable file works as expected. What could the problem be?

`update-alternatives --query gnome-www-browser` output:

```
Link: gnome-www-browser
Status: auto
Best: /opt/chromium-nightly/chrome
Value: /opt/chromium-nightly/chrome

Alternative: /opt/chromium-nightly/chrome
Priority: 1200

Alternative: /usr/bin/firefox
Priority: 40
```

`update-alternatives --query x-www-browser` output:

```
Link: x-www-browser
Status: auto
Best: /opt/chromium-nightly/chrome
Value: /opt/chromium-nightly/chrome

Alternative: /opt/chromium-nightly/chrome
Priority: 1200

Alternative: /usr/bin/firefox
Priority: 40
```

`xdg-settings get default-web-browser` output:

```
chromium-nightly.desktop
```

`cat /usr/share/applications/chromium-nightly.desktop` output:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Chromium Nightly
Comment=Browse the Web
Exec=/opt/chromium-nightly/chrome
Icon=/opt/chromium-nightly/product_logo_48.png
```

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,